# How to read MSDN API correctly. (eg. IDbSetExtensions.AddOrUpdate)

Tags: c#, .net

For example, if you go to IDbSetExtensions.AddOrUpdate Method (IDbSet, Expression>, TEntity[]) page on MSDN -- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh846514(v=vs.103).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1 --, you see that it takes three params. IDbSet, Expression and TEntity.

But what people usually write is like the below.

AddOrUpdate(item => new{item.Text}, itemArray); -- for the "seed method" within migrations.

My questions are:

1. How come there's only 2 params provided, not 3 and it's still ok?
2. What will be the difference between "AddOrUpdate(item => item.Text, itemArray)" and "AddOrUpdate(item => new{item.Text}, itemArray)" where first one there's no new operator.
3. When you're programming, do I need to know what every single line (within a project template) is doing?

I started project using template, so I don't have complete understanding of what it's doing but it sure takes time to dissect the whole template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Method you're looking at is an extension method. That's why you can call it with the first parameter missing.

   If you look closely, you can see that the method is static, which means it should be called using the class name, which is `IDbSetExtensions.AddOrUpdate`. However, because it is an extension method (`this` modifier in front of the first method argument makes that happen), you can call it as if it was an instance method of the type of the first method argument, in this case `IDbSet<TEntity>`.

   Read more about extension methods on MSDN: [Extension Methods (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx)
2. For `AddOrUpdate(item => item.Text, itemArray)` generic type `TObject` will get inferred to be whatever the type of `item.Text` is (probably a `string`). For `AddOrUpdate(item => new{item.Text}, itemArray)` is will be inferred as anonymous type, with one property.
3. You definitely should.

Comment: Well, shouldn't the first argument (this IDbSet<TEntity> set) have to be provided like * AddOrUpdate(this IDbSet<TEntity> set = DbSet<TEntity> ,item => item.Text, itemArray) * though? It's still a bit mysterious that omitting argument is ok. Am I still missing something?

Comment: First argument is the instance you call the method on.

Answer (score 0):

> How come there's only 2 params provided, not 3 and it's still ok?

The method call `AddOrUpdate(item => new{item.Text}, itemArray)` only passes two parameters, which is the same number of parameters as `AddOrUpdate(item => item.Text, itemArray)`.

> What's the difference

The method call with `new {item.Text}` returns an anonymous type with (assuming item.Text is a string) a string property called `Text` that has the value of item.Text.  The other method returns a string.

> Do you need to know what every single line is doing?

No.  Only, the compiler *needs* to know.  But it will help you write software if you know what the code does.

Comment: Didn't see that, @MarcinJuraszek has the right answer for that respect, `this` in a method parameter marks the method as an extension method.  The compiler automatically passes in the `set` so you don't have to by rewriting `myDbSet.AddOrUpdate(xxx, yyy)` as `IDbSetExtensions.AddOrUpdate(myDbSet, xxx, yyy)`